# Windows 7 to define a proxy for a range of IP addresses and hostnames only

Tags: windows-7, proxy

Is it possible within Windows 7 to define a proxy for a range of IP addresses and hostnames only? I understand individual applications may indeed have individual proxy settings but in this case the ones I’m looking to control are going by those defined within Internet Options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Proxycap](http://www.proxycap.com/) can do this although that it is paid, an alternative free version could be [Proxfier](http://www.proxifier.com/).